# How to normalize a world matrix?

Tags: matrix, normalization, matrix-multiplication

Here's my situation:
I have a world matrix.  I'm scaling to be half-size, so multiplying (0,0),(1,1), and (2,2) by .5f

When I do this, the normals in the mesh I'm trying to display become half-sized too, which kills a glare effect I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to get the scale of that matrix back to 1.0 without having to remember the scale value so it can be multiplied back it?  Is it possible to normalize a matrix so that it retains its rotation, but is scaled to 1.0 and is translated to 0,0,0?

Comment: Why can't you just renormalize the normal? If it's a uniform scale, that'd work out fine.

Comment: You can use a separate matrix to scale the normals, and not scale that one. Note that if you scale non-uniformly (e.g. stretch along one axis), then the normals have to be recomputed.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't want to throw a normalize into my vertex shader, just for speed reasons.

Comment: @user253751 In my case I'm scaling uniformly.  But isn't there a trick to get the matrix's scale back to 1:1?  I tried treating all the columns as vectors, and normalized them... and that SEEMS to work.  Is that a bad solution that will bite me later?

Comment: @KiraHoneybee "*I don't want to throw a normalize into my vertex shader, just for speed reasons.*" But another matrix multiplication is OK for performance? Vector normalization isn't especially expensive.

Comment: *"I don't want to throw a normalize into my vertex shader, just for speed reasons."*. If you interpolate your normals between vertex and fragment shader, you should very likely already normalize them. (linear interpolation doesn't yield unit length normals).

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) you just make the 3 direction vectors unit ... however the matrix MUST BE ORTHOGONAL so no skew or perspective or any other projection breaking orthogonality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much tweaking and testing, I did find that, for my purposes, simply treating each column as a vector and normalizing them yielded the results I wanted: A matrix that scaled to 1:1 while retaining the rotational information.

Leaving this up because I wasn't able to find this quick answer with a web search.